# VBA, Insert a new row and show a box where the user can fill in the values that need to be in de cells

Tags: vba, excel

I just created a VBA code where the user can click on a button and a new row is added. Now I need text box to show up (after the user has clicked on the button) for a range of cells where the user is asked to fill in values that come in the cell. Hope someone can help me.

Current code:

```
Sub Button6_Click()
    Sheets("Blad4").Range("C5").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlRight
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your VBA code actually *store* a new record, or is that what you *plan* for the future? And is your plan really to be: (a) Click; (b) Ask user for data; (c) Store new record?  How about posting the code you have now so we can take a look?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the code that I have now is:                             Sub Button6_Click()

Sheets("Blad4").Range("C5").Select
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlRight

End Sub.                                                                                                                How you said it is exactly how I want it. hope you can help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code that will prompt a user to enter some value. The problem I have is understanding your requirements. In one case you say you want to add a ROW, yet your code adds a COLUMN. Which is it??  And how many cells do you need to fill with user input, and are they all in the same row or the same column?  If you want 3 or more cells filled, it is horrible to ask a user three or more questions. If you can have the user delimit the value for each cell (i.e. :, or |, or ...) then that would be nice.

Please clarify above questions...

```
Sub Button6_Click()
Dim strUserValue    As String
    ' Ask user to enter a value. If you need values for several cells, then either
    ' ask several questions, or pars the value they enter (i.e. 'John:Doe:Jr.' could
    ' be split into three cells.
    strUserValue = InputBox("Enter Value", "Provide value for cells")
    Sheets("Results").Range("C5").Select                ' You are selecting this row & column
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlRight       ' This shifts the column right
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert               ' This inserts a new row relative to where you are (Active cell)
    Cells(6, 3) = strUserValue                          ' What row / column do you want to enter data in????
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually I have one button for adding a column and one for adding a row. If I know how to do one, I will know how to do the other. the cells I need to fill in with the user input are: For the column I need to fill in cells C5:C13 and C16:C28 and for the rowB6:K6 and B17:K17. But now I have the problem if I insert a column and than a row that the range will change. Though that I can fix this by an "if" condition. So if the cell is green a new input box appears where the user can fill in the value. if you want to take a look at the file yourself, I can send it in an email to you

Comment: I'm still curious about the 'text box for users to enter values' part. If I'm your user and you prompt me with 20+ textboxes, I'm not going to be happy. Have you thought about either allowing the user to enter directly into the sheet cells (you can protect other cells); or provide a user form for their input? Yes, as you add rows and columns you will need to 'remember' where you are. You could do that with either a global variable, or some code that will find the correct cell.

Comment: It is for a school assignment so it is mandatory to write a code for it. will try to figure it out. your code was a good direction on the first step

Comment: (1) Are you going to add another button that will indicate you want to add a column (you said you have a button to add a row)? If not, what will indicate whether a row or column? (2) Will the row or column always be added relative to where the 'ACTIVE CELL' is, or will you always add a row or column relative to where the last row/column was added?